# How to get rid from exception while finding last item in the list if an integer list is empty in C#

Tags: c#

I have an integer list as below

```
List<int> lstNumber = new List<int>();
lstNumber.Add(1);
lstNumber.Add(2);
int Number = lstNumber.Last();
```

Here we got value 2 in the integer variable `Number`.
If the list is empty, I get an exception when trying to find the last element.

See code sample:

```
List<int> lstNumber= new List<int>();
int Number=lstNumber.Last();
```

Here I'm getting an exception. How can I avoid this exception?

Comment: `LastOrDefault` would return `0`. You could also check `if (lstNumber.Any())` beforehand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `LastOrDefault()` instead of `Last()` if you are not sure about whether list is empty or not. `LastOrDefault()` would return `default(T)` if you don't have element inside the collection. In your case `default(int)` so following code would result in Number having 0 value.

```
List<int> lstNumber= new List<int>();
int Number=lstNumber.LastOrDefault(); // will not throw exception even though no element is there.
```

You can refer to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301849(v=vs.95).aspx) MSDN documentation for more details.